# CSS percentage with decimals only working correctly in Chrome (Firefox and Opera are just rounding up)

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, opera

I'm having an issue applying a `CSS Width` with a percentage and a decimal (e.g 33.33) to a div.

It seems to work fine in Chrome but plays up in Opera and Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/nhkz9/1/

Opera and Firefox both just round the percentage up, and because of insufficient `width` in the container, the third div moves to a new line. But when the percentages are not rounded up, there is enough space for all three to fit in one line.

any ideas on how i could fix this issue?

thanks

Comment: In the demo you posted I don't see to have anywhere 33.33% width.

Comment: @Sotiris Yeah I know, that was just used as an example.

Comment: When changing all the widths of your fiddle in Opera 11.61 to 33.33%, all 3 divs are on the same line.

Comment: @fivedigit but Opera has still rounded them all up. Can you see the small gap at the end there? That doesn't show up in Chrome. So Opera is rounding them all up to `33%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demo you posted adds `1px` border to two of the `<div>`s. By default this is not included in the 33.33% calculation, so your `<div>`s will never fit. To change this, use `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: ah right. So if this is the issue, why does it seem to work in Chrome? Thanks

Comment: @nav_nav You have widths of 33.1% of 80% of the body width.  Chrome will take 33.1% times the 80% and then round down to the nearest integer pixel.  That means things will fit, but will have gaps between them.  On the other hand, other browsers actually do subpixel positioning to handle cases like this, so that as long as your lengths actually add up to 100% (which yours don't) you won't have gaps.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky http://jsfiddle.net/nhkz9/5/embedded/result/ In Opera and Firefox, there is a gap at the end, although all three percentages equal out to be 100% (33.3333333%). And in Chrome, the third box goes to a new line.

Comment: @nav_nav The boder-box widths of the boxes there are 33.333333% plus 1px because they have a 1px border.  So no, they don't add up to 100%.  I see the third box go to a new line in Firefox too, for what it's worth.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky So I've now removed the border, and the gap still appears in Opera but not in Firefox or Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/nhkz9/7/embedded/result/

Comment: @nav_nav Yeah, no idea what Opera is doing there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`{max-width: 33.334%; min-width: 33.333%;}` instead of `{width: 33.333%}`

For all browsers it will be:

`.class {max-width: 33.334%; min-width: 33.333%; *width: 33.333%;}`

It's not ideal. `+-1px` still left in some browsers, but... that is better than 1%